# Anyway to replicate a tuple of different elements in Java?

Tags: java, tuples

Consider the question Maximum depth of a binary tree but solve it iteratively. The question:https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-depth-of-binary-tree/

This is how I would do it in python

```
def maxDepth(self, root):
    """
    :type root: TreeNode
    :rtype: int
    """
    if(root == None):
        return 0
    
    stack = [(root, 1)] # (treeNode, depth)
    max_depth = 1
    while(stack != []):
        node, depth = stack.pop()
        if(node.left):
            stack.append((node.left, depth + 1))
        if(node.right):
            stack.append((node.right, depth + 1))
        max_depth = max(max_depth, depth)
    return max_depth
```

This is how I would do it in Java

```
public int maxDepth(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null)
        return 0;
    
    Stack <TreeNode> nodes = new Stack <>();
    Stack <Integer> countNodes = new Stack <>();
    int max = 1;
    
    nodes.push(root);
    countNodes.push(1);
    
    while (!nodes.isEmpty()) {
        TreeNode cur = nodes.pop();
        int curNodeCount = countNodes.pop();
        
        
        
        if (cur.left != null) {
            nodes.push(cur.left);
            countNodes.push(curNodeCount + 1);
        }
            
        if (cur.right != null) {
            nodes.push(cur.right);
            countNodes.push(curNodeCount + 1);
        }
        max = Math.max(max, curNodeCount);
    }
    
    return max;
}
```

Just wondering is there a way to make a tuple of (TreeNode node, int depth) so I could avoid having to make two stacks in Java? (Like how I did it in python).

Comment: Java does not have built-in ```tuple```.     And  **solve it iteratively**  : you can use one queue instead of two stacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no concept of a tuple in Java, these are some ways you can do this in Java. That is, your `Stack` will now contain instances of one of these, instead of having one `Stack` per element.

### Using a class that contains the required fields

- Create a class like this:

```java
public class YourClass{
    private TreeNode node;
    private int depth;
    //Getters, Setters
}
```

- Use an instance of this class as your "tuple"

### Use Object[]

- Here you create an `Object[]` of the desired size (2, in this case) and set the values to it

```java
Object[] tuple = new Object[]{ treeNode, depth };
```

- Access the elements using indices

### Use Map<String, Object>

This is not really a tuple, of course. But it is a good solution for many such scenarios.

- Create a map with named keys and put values into it

```java
Map<String, Object> tuple = new HashMap<>();
tuple.put( "treeNode", treeNode );
tuple.put( "depth", depth );
```

- Access the elements using keys

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pair class:

```
public int maxDepth(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null)
        return 0;

    Stack<Pair<TreeNode, Integer>> stack = new Stack<>();
    int max = 1;
    stack.push(new Pair<>(root,1));

    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        Pair<TreeNode, Integer> curPair = stack.pop();
        TreeNode cur = curPair.getKey();
        int curNodeCount = curPair.getValue();

        if (cur.left != null)
            stack.push(new Pair<>(cur.left, curNodeCount + 1));

        if (cur.right != null)
            stack.push(new Pair<>(cur.right, curNodeCount + 1));

        max = Math.max(max, curNodeCount);
    }

    return max;
}
```